# how can i authorizing with jdbcRealm-Shiro in java SE

Tags: java, shiro, jdbcrealm

I need to know how can I doing **authorization** with MySQL in Shiro.

All examples that I could find through web were about authorization in WebApps.
I need it in **SE application** but there isn't too much information about jdbcRealm.

please help me.

**thanks**

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Have you tried to connect to a mysql server in pure java ? for example `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB";`